# On the shortest vector problem (is it $NP$-complete?)

Tags: np-hardness, np-complete, derandomization, lattice, integer-lattice

Ajtai has shown that shortest vector problem is $NP$-hard by using [randomized reduction from subset sum](http://www.csie.nuk.edu.tw/~cychen/Lattices/The%20shortest%20vector%20problem%20in%20L2%20is%20NP-hard%20for%20randomized%20reductions%20(extended%20abstract).pdf).

Has this been derandomized?

Comment: I think this is still an open problem. Here is a reference from 2012, for example: http://www.theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v008a022/v008a022.pdf. This paper from 2014 mentions only randomized reductions https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7994

Comment: @SashoNikolov thank you. one more small point to clarify. Does the SVP problem inherently have an unique solution or at least just at most a slowly growing number (that is do we have much choice in picking shortest basis upto signs)?

Comment: @SashoNikolov 'unique solution upto signs or at least just at most a slowly growing number upto signs'.

Comment: In the integer lattice $\mathbb{Z}^n$ the shortest nonzero vectors are the standard basis vectors (and their negations), which is $n$ vectors up to signs. I am not sure what the best upper bound on the number of shortest vectors is.

Comment: After some more thought: The number of shortest nonzero vectors in a lattice is at least (exactly?) the largest kissing number of a lattice packing of balls. This is known to be at least $2^{\Omega(\log^2 n)}$ in dimension $n$, and I think it is consistent with current knowledge that it may be exponential in $n$.

Comment: @SashoNikolov great comment. Thank you but why does kissing number count shortest basis or if not why does it lower bound ?

Comment: @SashoNikolov also could you provide reference for the superpoly lower bound you are quoting?

Comment: for kissing numer SVP connection I see [here](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/damien.stehle/downloads/SVPCVP.pdf). I still do not know the superpoly lower bound.

Comment: see for example section 3.4. of this [paper by Leech](https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v16/cjm1964v16.0657-0682.pdf).

Comment: @SashoNikolov: Everything you said is right. I think you should make your comments into an answer. A couple of comments: $\ell_\infty$-SVP is known to be NP-hard under deterministic reductions using a similar reduction to the one used to show NP-hardness for CVP. $\ell_p$-SVP is NP-hard even to approximate within any constant factor for any $p > 1$ (http://www.cs.nyu.edu/~khot/papers/j-svp.ps).